# Unobtrusive jQuery Validation Using MVC3 and Razor Fail

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model Izdivac.Models.User  
@using(Html.BeginForm("Basics", "User", FormMethod.Post , new { id="aboutme"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <ul> 
            <li>
                <label>Username</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new {@class = "input-text size-xl"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username) 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>First Name</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "input-text size-xl"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {@class = "input-text size-xl"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) 
            </li> 
            <li>
                <label>Gender</label>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.BasicInfo.Gender)
            </li>
         <li>
                <input type="submit" class="input-button" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#aboutme').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {

                    $('#ShowResultHere').html(result.s);
                }
            }); 
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I m trying to do client side validation without hitting the server and failing.

how can i fix this? why is this failing?

EDIT:

here is model:

```
public class User
{ 
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { set; get; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { set; get; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string FullName { set; get; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var formValid = $("#aboutme").validate().form();

        if (!formValid) return false;
```

Did it.

Comment: What about replacing the if with `return formValid` ? :)

Comment: Thansk for the comment, but if it s false, it stops, otherwise goes on to the rest of the script.